# controller not getting called , when i click on same templateUrl in angularjs router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have router

```
     templateUrl: 'xyz.html',
     controller: 'appDetailsCtrl'
```

When i click on tab frist time which gives xyz.html template url my appDetailsCtrl getting called
But when i reclicked on my tab , my controller not getting called.
My Senario : I am populating with http request call , and this service called in appDetailsCtrl and data updated in UI, when i clicked the same button controller didnt get called.

Similar post i saw here; 
[Why angularjs controller is not called when i click the button again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377439/why-angularjs-controller-is-not-called-when-i-click-the-button-again)

I dont have points to comment there and it dint get answered, so rasing new question
Finally,

How can i call my service on 2nd time(there after) click,

i need to update the in UI after calling myservice

Comment: angularjs router routes only if different path is passed in so in your case you can add a click  function on your tab and call $state.reload() there..

Comment: Cant i do anything in router, rather then having onclick function for this in element

Comment: I haven't got anything but this is got to be fine I guess..Its why we attach a callback function and whenever it is clicked we can do appropriate task..

Comment: I dont have that controller in my page , it is available in main, cant add any button actions there, i will get url click to my page, so i need to in the same page only